# Regular expression: length between and must contain alphabet < 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to use for ID card

- Must contain number
- Can contain A-z between 0 to 3 chars. (Can be anywhere)
- No space
- Overall length between 9 to 19.

I tried with this one but it is mean 'Must contain both number and A-Z'

```
^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

Example what I need

- 1234567890 ✓
- ABC12345678 ✓
- ABCD12345678 ✕
- AB12345C6789 ✓
- 1234ABC567890 ✓
- 1234ABCE56789 ✕

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you always -1 people?, you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: what? I did not try to answer. Your question is not precise enough to know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookahead for the first 2 conditions, and character class for condition 3 and 4:

```
Must contain number             : (?=.*\d)
Can contain 0 to 3 letter       : (?=(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]?\d*){0,3}$)
No space                        : included in the next condition
Overall length between 9 to 19. : [a-zA-Z\d]{9,19}
```

Group them together:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]?\d*){0,3}$)[a-zA-Z\d]{9,19}$/
```

You could simplified it using case insensitive flag:

```js
var test = [
'1234567890',
'ABC12345678',
'ABCD12345678',
'AB12345C6789',
'1234ABC567890',
'1234ABCE56789'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?=.*\d)(?=(?:\d*[a-z]?\d*){0,3}$)[a-z\d]{9,19}$/i.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: I tried this out in regex101.com Everything work fine except for number only like 1234567890, what am I do wrong?

Comment: @selfclose:Sorry, I've done a mistake, add `?` after character class like`[a-z]?`. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

In general regex it looks somewhat like this `[A-Za-z0-9]{9,19}` and `[A-Za-z]{0,3}`. I suppose in javascript it looks similar. Is this what you need?

Comment: thanks for answer, but I need in 1 condition like
^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$

Comment: @selfclose would you care to provide an example of what should be matched (edit your question)?